# "JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape" while trying to load JSON into Python dict

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load JSON into a python dict:

```
>>> d
'[{"amount":"0","categories":["test","test2","test3"],"categoryIds":["A001G001","A003E001A001","A003G002A001","A003T001A001"]}]'
```

Unfortunatelly I do get an error message which I could not get around:

```
>>> json.loads(d, strict=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 361, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 410 (char 409)
```

How can I load the JSON into a python dictionary?

Comment: You simplified the code too much that it no longer creates the error; nevertheless it's a duplicate of [python - simplejson.loads() get Invalid \escape: 'x' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296041/simplejson-loads-get-invalid-escape-x?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

There is an object within the `json`:

```
{"amount":"0","categories":["Gereizte Haut","Gesichtspflege f\xFCr allergische Haut","Insektenstiche","Sonnenallergie & Mallorca-Akne","Basispflege & Reinigung"],"categoryIds":["A001G002","HN001A002G001","HN001A002I002","HN001A002S001","HN001N001B001"],"name":"Linola akut 0,5% Creme","price":969,"pzn":"02138990"}
```

with the string: `"Gesichtspflege f\xFCr allergische Haut"` which is not valid json.

You need to get your source to encode the data properly.

Comment: These are umlaut characters in german which have been encoded differently. So, as you've mentioned with correct encoding the code would work.